# react2.default.render is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I'm doing a video course from Packt on React. I'm trying to build a component.

Unfortunately I think the video course is a little outdated.

When I save my js file with a component I get this message in the browser console:

index.js:19240 Uncaught TypeError: _react2.default.render is not a function

My package.json looks like this:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/396478849378a7a31c2dfc3fe8290ed4

My webpack config looks like this:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/43fa0751262b5faab1e6910ce53b1c0d

My own script looks like this:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6936234da970dadaf4b06e3f9e95e404

My guess is that I'm using either the wrong call to render the component, or that I'm using an outdated react package.

What do I need to do in order to successfully call a method for rendering the component?

Answer (score 3):

To render a react element into a DOM node, you should use ReactDOM.render(). `So, replace React.render(component, document.getElementById('react'))  with ReactDom.render(component, document.getElementById('react')) in your script`https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6936234da970dadaf4b06e3f9e95e404

For more info, visit https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html